# impala - does it require hdfs and namenodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, impala

Can Apache Impala install/run on EC2s (not EMR) reading data from S3? Or does it require Hadoop Namenodes and HDFS to work?
The documentation is not very clear on installation dependencies.

Comment: Impala can read from S3 (it will be need to copy data into local HDFS, which does require a namenode), but EMR Presto or some other AWS Managed service would make more sense

Comment: @cricket_007 any source? Amos below claims hdfs not required

Comment: See my comment below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, Impala can run without hdfs. The only component it requires from the hadoop ecosystem is hive-metastore, which it uses to store metadata.

As for S3 accessiblity, you can refer to https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/impala_s3.html

Comment: any source for it not requiring hdfs?

Comment: @tooptoop4 well you can run it locally and see how it works. Here is how it works in general: Impala supports multifarious table types such as native tables stored in hdfs with parquet format, kudu tables, hbase tables or even external tables. Without hdfs you only lose the ability to create native tables. It doesn't prevent you from using the other types.

Comment: In your link **Impala requires that the default filesystem for the cluster be HDFS. You cannot use S3 as the only filesystem in the cluster**

Comment: @cricket_007 ah, I should be more careful when reading the question instead of just the title. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm trying to only using Impala and Kudu without HDFS. But i get an error saying "Currently configured default filesystem: ProxyLocalFileSystem. fs.defaultFS (file:///) is not supported"  only goes away when i install and start HDFS. 
can Impala and Kudu work without HDFS?